# Java Web Start launched in Finder says no JRE available. Works fine in console

Tags: macos, java

Followed solution here - [Java for OS X 2012-006: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559)
 to restore browser java plug-in, works fine now.

But still can not launch jnlp application. If I launch it by simply double-clicking in finder I get message that I need to download Java Runtime Environment.

At the same time if I use terminal and write `javaws myapp.jnlp` it launches correctly.

What the issue may be and how can I fix it?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

Update: I have updated to 1.7 and now it works correctly. Just for your information.

Comment: What does `java -version` show? What OS X version do you use?

Comment: I believe the latest Apple update - 1.6.0_37

Comment: It'd be great if you *knew* it :-) I asked because I installed Oracle Java 7 on my MacBook Pro but LibreOffice complained and OS X wanted to install Java. I finally gave up, uninstalled Java 7 and installed Apple's Java. I wonder what would get installed on your Mac if you accepted the request to download a JRE...

Comment: If I click on 'More info' button in the window I get transferred to Oracle site which offers Java 7 to install. Updated Java information.